# Program to help synchronize folder structures, with a twist

Tags: windows, gratis, linux, open-source, file-synchronization

I am looking for a "[file-synchronization](/questions/tagged/file-synchronization)" tool (you'll understand the quotes shortly) with the following properties:

- cross-platform (Linux and Windows at a minimum)

  - this implies that it should be agnostic to `/` vs. `\` issues ...
- single-master ... i.e. there is one authoritative copy
- stores cryptographic hash of the files under its control along with other metadata in some database

  - file name
  - file path
  - timestamps
- it should be able to detect files whose location (or name) underneath the base folder changed (but whose file size and hash will obviously be the same)

  - can use the file size as well as head and tail of multi-[GiB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibibyte) files to make a quick call on whether it should even bother to compare the full cryptographic hash
- doesn't have to do the actual synchronization (copying files around, verifying them afterward), instead it's sufficient to give a report in a form that I can post-process with a script, for example (i.e. structured output in whatever commonly used format such as YAML, JSON, XML or even CSV ...)

I'd prefer FLOSS and gratis, but if the solution is comprehensive, I will definitely shell out up to, say, 50 bucks (USD).

Comment: Why not consider just using a version control tool such as git or mercurial. They do almost exactly what you are describing __plus__ letting you track what has changed and being able to revert it?

Comment: @SteveBarnes simple, because the files are huge and binary. `git-annex` would generally be an option, but that would require using Git. And Git hates me and I it, so I won't use it voluntarily without being paid to do so. I was actually wondering when I wrote my question if I should mention having pondered these options.